# Disable event buffer SDL2 when holding down a key

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, sdl

I'm currently developing a server-client game and I'm having trouble with SDL2 event queue. The following code is used to move the character:

```cpp
void handleEvent( SDL_Event& e) {

    if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) {

        switch( e.key.keysym.sym ) {

            case SDLK_LEFT:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;

            case SDLK_UP:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;
        }
    }

    else if( e.type == SDL_KEYUP ) {

        switch( e.key.keysym.sym ) {

            case SDLK_LEFT:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;

            case SDLK_UP:
                // Do something and send key to server
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

There seems to be some kind of event buffer when a key is being hold down. Basically if I rapidly tap the arrow keys, the keys are instantly sent to the server. But when I hold down the arrow I instantly get only one key message (the initial tap one) and after 200ms I start getting the stream of keys. The behaviour I am aiming for is to always get the stream of the key being pressed at that time asap.

I am purposely avoiding the use of (e.key.repeat == 0) because I need to send every key press to the server to update the server's character logic object position correctly.

Comment: Key repeat usually controlled by operating system, both initial delay and repeat interval. You get the same behaviour in text editor if you hold a key. You can ignore repeated events and generate whatever you want at fixed intervals relying only on press/release events.